# High-speed PCB crosstalk, inductive vs capacitive

Tags: pcb, microwave, signal-integrity, high-speed, crosstalk

I know that at the time of crosstalk Capacitive as well as inductive currents generate voltage drops on the victim line over termination resistors.

I have three questions.

1)Why inductive crosstalk current more than capacitive crosstalk current.
(In the far end in microstrip environment the total current is inductive current-capacitive current here the inductive component of current dominates ).

2)Why in forward direction inductive crosstalk current and capacitive crosstalk current are
opposite.

3)Why in backward direction inductive crosstalk current and capacitive crosstalk current are
equal.

Comment: Capacitive current injected to a victim wire is not the same as the current in an adjacent wire inducing voltage on the victim wire hence, your questions seem to be missing the some direction.

Comment: there exists a nice YouTube video with Eric Bogatin on this matter.

Comment: @tobalt https://youtu.be/EF7SxgcDfCo

Comment: Related to point 1: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/570995/are-the-amplitudes-of-the-electric-field-and-the-magnetic-field-of-an-electromag

Comment: Eric Bogatin's power and signal integrity textbook has a very intuitive explanation of inductive and capacitive coupling in crosstalk. It's still something like 40 pages long I think, so much longer than can be addressed here. Look up his talks or get a copy of his book.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where all the claims in your questions come from, but to me it does not make much sense (e.g. why inductive current more than capacitive current? Do you have a source for that claim?)

Let's shortly recap: There is inductive and capacitive crosstalk. Inductive crosstalk happens because of magnetic field. Capacitive crosstalk happens because of electric field. So it's the strength of magnetic or electric field that defines the current. So one or the other current is more dominant.